# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{x} \cdot \sqrt[n]{y} = \sqrt[n]{x \cdot y}$

Tags: radicals

I am currently learning about properties of radicals in a high school math class, and I am curious as to why this property holds true?

$\sqrt[n]{x} \cdot \sqrt[n]{y} = \sqrt[n]{x \cdot y}$

Could anyone intuitively explain this to me?

Comment: This is the general property of exponentiantion: $$(a \cdot b)^n=a^n \cdot b^n$$ Now apply it you your expression: you will just get: $$x \cdot y=x \cdot y$$ because by definition $$(\sqrt[n]{a})^n=a$$

Comment: Important note: if $n$ is even then this is only true for $x,y>0$.

Comment: Yuriy S
I understand that you can do this:

        $\sqrt[n]{x} = x^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Is this what you are telling me to apply?

Comment: Yes, and see @Wojowu comment. Of course I meant, $x,y>0$ for even $n$

Comment: Yuriy S Ah so basically I can just make that expression:    
$(\sqrt[n]{x} \cdot \sqrt[n]{y})^{n} = (\sqrt[n]{x \cdot y})^{n}$ to yield $x \cdot y = x \cdot y$     
I guess that's pretty intuitive, although I wish there was something more visual.

Comment: Wojowu      
Is this because if $n$ was even then the answer for both the radicals in the left expression could be either positive or negative, therefor I would have 4 different possible answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sqrt[n]{a}$ and $\sqrt[n]{b}$ are defined and real for real $a,b$, this is true.

Note that $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$. So if $x=\sqrt[n]{a}$ and $y=\sqrt[n]{b}$ then $$(xy)^n=\left(\sqrt[n]{a}\sqrt[n]{b}\right)^n = (\sqrt[n]{a})^n(\sqrt[n]{b})^n=ab$$

So $z=\sqrt[n]{a}\sqrt[n]{b}$ satisfies $z^n= ab$. So $z=\sqrt[n]{ab}$ by definition. (You'll need some additional arguments that $z$ is the right sign when $n$ is even, but that is easy.)

Comment: Thanks, this was well explained and I now understand.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks, @surb

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You still had a couple of lingering typos so I corrected them. Hope you don't mind.